# I want sialog flow to start the intent, the user to answer and dialog flow to reply again

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to build a bot simulating an aviation test. Google simulates the pilot and the user is the ATC controller.
Usually a dialog works like this in aviation:
Pilot(google): Tower, AmericanAirlines runway vacated, request taxi instructions to stand tango 10.
ATC(user): Roger, taxi via alpha and bravo to stand tango 10.
Pilot(google): via alpha and bravo to stand tango 10, AmericanAirlines.

It will be a series of different small snippet dialogs like this kind of telling the story of the planes flightpath (landing clearance, runway vacated, ...) So i thought I make an intent for each. In the Text response I could put the text from the last dialog and then straight away the next text, where the user has to answer to. But this would not simulate reality, where there is a time gap between the two (landing clearance and vacating runway for example).
I tried to setup webhook and then trigger the next by setfollowupevent. But then the text is skipped.

```
  function welcome(agent) {
agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
agent.setFollowupEvent('next_event');
```

}

e.g. like this.
Any idea how I could solve this? it is not really a dialog bot because the first response comes from the bot, followed by the test question from the user and then acknowledged by the bot again.

Any help is appreciated cause I can't really find anything in the doc.
Thanks.

Comment: In this [issue](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/102) similar behavior was reported, please take a look there it  could help  you to understand how to solve this.

Comment: I did find this but couldn't really use it as no proper solution was suggested. I'll try Amazon Alexa as I'm in the beginning of my project, found SSML there, where you can add proper pauses when replying, this should help me. For anyone having similar issues: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#break

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/ssml) SSML is also available in Dialogflow when using Google Assistant.